# FileManager-Actions in wrong directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, file-manager

I want to create an action to open in VS Code with FileManager-Actions.
The problem is that whenever I execute the action, it opens VS Coded on the parent directory.
For example if I want to execute the action on main/second/third it opens the editor on main/second
[This is my FileManager configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAhuy.png)

I also Tried changing the Working directory or Parameters but to no avail.
Does anyone know the correct configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783292/what-do-the-various-percent-parameters-in-context-menu-actions-or-desktop-f).
It said:

> `%d` (first) base directory
> `%f` The path to the first selected file

Though `%f` represents the selected file, it can also be the current folder path when right click on the blank space in the a folder.
So I replaced `%d` with `%f` and solved this problem. Hope it can help you.